# Show that this polynomial has three different real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

There is polynomial $f(x)=x^3 +ax^2+bx+c$ and $ab=9c$ and $b<0$. Like in the title. I've only come up so far with $9x^3 + 9ax^2 + 9bx+ab=0$ and factoring here does nothing.

Comment: What tools do you get to use?

Comment: I deleted my answer because the last term is just $ab$ not $9ab$. I'm no longer sure this thing has to have three distinct roots.

Comment: Do you, for instance, know the discriminant of the cubic?

Comment: @AlfredYerger : The minimum of the discriminant is $-4 b^3$, so this has three real roots.

Comment: Do you know Descartes rule of signs?

Comment: So the number of positive roots is equal to 2 or 0 and 1 negative? We now need to search fo r one positive real root to prove it its not 0?

Comment: Hmm...  Do we know $a,b,c$ are real numbers?  That $b$ is real is implicit in the inequality.

Comment: There is no more data besides this equation $ab=9c$ .But its a high school problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have expanded Eric Towers' comments into an answer.  Hope this can help OP.  The second method <del>is *more efficient and error-prone*</del> doesn't work well, unlike the first one.

## Method 1: Discriminant

Given that $ab=9c$ and $b<0$, the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_discriminant) is
\begin{align}
\Delta &= 18(1)abc-4a^3c+a^2b^2-4(1)b^3-27(1)^2c^2 \\
&= 162c^2-4a^3c+81c^2-4b^3-27c^2 \\
&= 216c^2-4a^3c-4b^3 \\
&= 4\left(54c^2-a^3c-b^3\right) \\
&= 4\left[54c^2-\left(\frac{9c}{b}\right)^3c-b^3\right] \\
&= 4\left[54c^2+\frac{3^6c^4}{(-b)^3}+(-b)^3\right] \\
&= \frac{4}{(-b)^3} \left[\left(3^3c^2\right)^2+2\left(3^3c^2\right)(-b)^3+(-b)^6\right] \\
&= \frac{4}{\underbrace{(-b)^3}_{b<0}} (\underbrace{27c^2}_{\ge0}+\underbrace{(-b)^3}_{b<0})^2 > 0
\end{align}
Hence $f(x)=x^3 +ax^2+bx+c$ has three distinct real roots.

## Method 2: Descartes rule of signs

**Edit: As pointed out in the comments, this argument is *incomplete*.  I tried proof by contradiction, and dividing by $x-r$ ($r$ is the positive root) in the case $a>0$, but I *can't* figure out how this works.**

*I'm [leaving this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27423/290189), hoping some motivated user complete this*

Refer to [Wiki's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Example:_real_roots) to know how to apply this result.

Rewrite $f(x)=x^3 +ax^2+bx+c$ into an array of $\pm$: $(+,?,-,?)$.  Since $ab=9c$ with $b<0$, *the first and the third $?$'s are opposite to each other*.

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Case} & \text{+ve roots} & \text{-ve roots} \\ \hline
a>0 & +,+,-,- & -,+,+,- \\
 & \text{1 sign change} & \text{2 sign changes} \\ \hline
a<0 & +,-,-,+ & -,-,+,+ \\
 & \text{2 sign changes} & \text{1 sign change} \\ \hline
a=0 & +,\phantom{+},-,\phantom{+} & -,\phantom{+},+,\phantom{+} \\
 & \text{1 sign change} & \text{1 sign change}
\end{array}

1. Divide the situation into three cases according to the sign of $a$.
2. Extract the signs from $f(x)$ and write them down in the first column.
3. Count the number of sign changes ($+,-$ or $-,+$) in each cell.  This represents the *parity* of the number of positive root(s) in each case.
4. Write down the signs for $f(-x)$ in the second column.

   - *Copy* the signs representing *even powers* of $x$.
   - *Invert* the signs representing *odd powers* of $x$.
5. Repeat (3) in the second column.  This represents the *parity* of the number of negative root(s) in each case.

- If $a\ne0$, **we can't conclude anything** from it.
- If $a=0$, the condition $ab=9c$ gives $c=0$, so $x=0$ is a root *not* counted by this method.  We have three distinct real roots.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thx for your edit !  The spacing and vertical alignment for the squares $^2$ in $$\left(3^3c^2\right)^2$$ `\left(3^3c^2\right)^2` looks better than my original version $$(3^3c^2)^2$$ `(3^3c^2)^2`.  I would be glad to know if there're any difference between `&=` and `=&`.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you are so welcome! I’m a bit of a [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) fanatic ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Don’t hold me to this, but I *believe* that when you follow `&` with a character like `=`, `>` etc., the program automatically knows to place a space on either side. On my platform I can definitely see a small space.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I'm just curious.  Btw, do you know [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)?  (Any markdown engine generating $\rm\TeX$-like document will do, but this software can convert markdown to MS Word/PPT/etc.)

Comment: Eric Towers went the other way, showing the result by (somewhat laborious) elementary means (and also explained that there must be an additional, missing constraint on $a$ and $c$ that is required for the rule of signs method).

Comment: @EricTowers You're right by adding back the constraint.  This is assumed in high school level though.  I mean I get the idea from your first two questions in the comments.

Comment: The discussion on Descartes rule of signs is incomplete.  The rule says that the number of roots has the same parity as the number of sign changes, and does not exceed the number of sign changes.  When you have one sign change, you have one root, but with two sign changes, all you know is that there are 0 or 2 roots.   How many positive roots has $x^2-2x+1000?$

Comment: @saulspatz You're right.  Sorry for my mistake.  I've marked my second way as not working.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the requirement that $a,c$ be real.  Set $a = 3\mathrm{i}$, $b = -3$, $c = -\mathrm{i}$.  Then $b < 0$, $ab = -9\mathrm{i} = 9c$, and $f(x) = x^3 + 3 \mathrm{i} x^2 - 3 x - \mathrm{i} = (x+\mathrm{i})^3$, so all three roots are the same and none are real.  Consequently, for the problem to be correct, another contraint is required.  That $a$, $b$, and $c$ must be real is a sufficient such constraint.

---

If $c = 0$, $ab=9c$ and $b<0$ force $a = 0$, so $f(x) = x^3 + bx = (x^2+b)x$, having the three real roots $\{-\sqrt{-b},0,\sqrt{-b}\}$, which are distinct.

From now on, we assume $c \neq 0$, so $0$ is not a root of $f$.  First we address two cases where the roots are real but have duplicates, showing that if the roots are real, they are distinct.  Then we show that having a conjugate pair of roots is impossible.

If the roots are real and not distinct, then either they are all the same or exactly two are the same.

Suppose (for purposes of contradiction) the roots are $u$, $u$, and $u$ (and $u \neq 0$).  $f(x) = (x-u)^3= x^3 - 3u x^2 + 3u^2 x - u^3$, so \begin{align*}
a &= -3u  \text{,}  \\
b &= 3u^2  \text{, and}  \\
c &= -u^3  \text{.}
\end{align*}
But this says $b > 0$.  So the three roots cannot all be the same.

Now suppose (for purposes of contradiction) the roots are $u$, $u$, and $v$ (and $u \neq 0$, $v \neq 0$, and $v \neq u$).  $f(x) = (x-u)^2(x-v) = x^3 -(2u+v)x^2 + (u^2 + 2uv)x - u^2 v$, so \begin{align*}
a &= -(2u+v)  \text{,}  \\
b &= u^2 + 2uv  \text{, and}  \\
c &= -u^2 v  \text{.}
\end{align*}
From $ab=9c$, \begin{align*}
-(2u+v)(u^2 + 2uv) &= 9(-u^2 v)  \\
-2u^3 -4 u^2 v - u^2 v - 2 uv^2 &= -9 u^2 v  \\
-2u^3 - 2 uv^2 &= -4 u^2 v  \\
-2u(u^2 - 2uv + v^2) &= 0  \\
-2u(u - v)^2 &= 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since a product is zero only if one (or more) of the multiplicands is zero, either $-2u=0$ or $(u-v)^2 = 0$.  The first says $u = 0$, a contradiction.  The second says $v = u$, a contradiction.  This shows not exactly two roots are the same.

Therefore, the if the roots are real, the three roots of $f$ are distinct.

The coefficients of $f$ are real.  (Assumed additional constraint, see the aside before this solution.)  Consequently, either all three roots are real, or one is real and two are a conjugate pair.  Suppose two are a conjugate pair so the roots are $u$, $v + \mathrm{i}w$, $v - \mathrm{i}w$.  By the above, we may take $u \neq 0$ and $w > 0$.  Then 
$f(x) = (x-u)(x-v - \mathrm{i}w)(x - v + \mathrm{i}w) = x^3 - (u+2v)x^2 + (2uv+v^2+w^2)x - (uv^2+uw^2)$, so \begin{align*}
a &= - (u+2v)  \text{,}  \\
b &= (2uv+v^2+w^2)  \text{, and}  \\
c &= - (uv^2+uw^2)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
If $v = 0$, from $ab=9c$,$-(u)(w^2) = -9(uw^2)$, so $8 uw^2 = 0$ and either $u=0$ (contradiction) or $w = 0$ (contradiction).  Therefore, $v \neq 0$.
From $ab=9c$, \begin{align*}
-(u+2v)(2uv+v^2+w^2) &= -9(uv^2+uw^2)  \\
-2u^2v -u v^2 -u w^2 - 4uv^2-2v^3-2vw^2 &= -9uv^2 -9uw^2  \\
-2u^2v -2v^3-2vw^2 &= -4uv^2 -8uw^2  \\
(-2v)u^2 +(4v^2 +8w^2)u -2v(v^2+w^2) &= 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}
By the quadratic formula, $u = \frac{1}{v}\left( v^2 + 2w^2 \pm w\sqrt{3v^2+4w^2} \right)$.  The only constraint we haven't used is $b < 0$, so we substitute these into the expression for $b$ and simplify to $b = 3v^2 + 5w^2 \pm 2w\sqrt{3v^2 + 4w^2}$.  If we pick the positive root, each term is positive, so we must take the negative root and have $2w\sqrt{3v^2 + 4w^2} > 3v^2 + 5w^2$.  Both sides are positive, so squaring only risks introducing negative solutions (of no interest to us), giving \begin{align*}
12v^2w^2 + 16 w^4 &> 9v^4 + 30 v^2w^2 + 25w^4  \\
0 &> 9v^4 + 18 v^2w^2 + 9w^4  \text{,}
\end{align*}
an impossibility.  Therefore, it is not the case that $f$ has a conjugate pair of roots.

Therefore, there are three distinct roots, all of which are real.